# Journey Builder Exclusion script for data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

So I used the following script to exclude a DE from my journey send.

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Exclusion_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME","EMAIL_ADDR_FIELD_NAME", EMAILADDR))>0
```

After adding in my find DE name and email field, I added it to two of my email messages in my Journey that has two messages for testing purposes.

After I ran my journey with that exclusion script in place for 2 of my messages, I have 10 contacts in my DE that I wanted to exclude and it appeared to work. I did not receive an email message to my inbox.

How would I confirm within Journey builder that this exclusion actually worked though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t an *easy* report that you can just pull that would tell you the [exclusion script](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320456&language=en_US&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&mode=1) has worked successfully. You essentially have to compare the records in your journey data extension to the records in the [_Sent data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5).

This can be done using a [SQL query activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) and using the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` statement.

For example, you have your Journey Data Extension and you can query the _Sent data view where `TriggeredSendCustomerKey` equals your journey send.

Your SQL query would contain a nested select statement.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM Sent_Journey s
WHERE s.email = j.email)
```

Comment: Thanks for the your answer!

I'll definitely look into this and do a compare.

Appreciate it.